# Grails war has no java source

Tags: grails, gradle, war, grails3

I'm trying to create a WAR file to deploy my Grails app on a Tomcat server.

But when I run:

```
grails war
```

I get the following output

[image: Grails war output]

I'm not able to run it on an external Tomcat server (I think this is related to the No-Source outputs)

On the other side, I'm able to run it without any problems using:

```
grails run-app
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have actual Java sources in your app? Why aren't you able to run your war?

Comment: Yes, I'm also able to run java -version and grails -version without any problem [versions' image](https://imgur.com/rvavexI) but when I build the app and try to run the war with `java -jar ...` command I get the following errors [image with the errors](https://imgur.com/a/3A7OCyN) that seems to be related with Hibernate (hibernateMapping)

Comment: I don't know if it's important or not, but I'm using an in-memory database (the default one) for this war test.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the type from `compile` to `provided` in `build.gradle` for the line:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

Comment: I'm getting the same outputs with `compileJava` and `compileWebappsGroovyPages` (No-source), also when I try to deploy it on Tomcat I get the following error: _Deploy failed: Excepción: [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null]_